# Adding blur changes div below

Tags: html, css

If I blur a div, the div below is changed, similarly to a linear gradient (screenshot below). Why does this happen and how could I solve it?
(I would like to have a clear cut between the two divs).

This is my code for the upper div:

```
.hero-banner-fourteen::before{
  background-image: url("../images/moje_slike/video7.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: -20px;
}

.hero-banner-fourteen {
  position: relative;
  padding: 200px 0 130px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero-banner-fourteen::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(20px);               //IF I ADD FILTER LOWER DIV CHANGES 
}
```

The html file:

```
      <div className="hero-banner-fourteen lg-container" id="home">
        <div className="container">
          <HeroBanner />
          <div className="screen-holder">
            <svg src="images/shape/241.svg" alt="" className="img-meta" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className="fancy-feature-thirtySix lg-container pt-170 pb-110 md-pt-120 md-pb-60"
        id="product"
      >
        <div className="container position-relative">
          <div className="row">
            <div
              className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4"
              data-aos="fade-right"
              data-aos-duration="1200"
            >
              <div className="title-style-eleven md-mb-40 text-center text-lg-left">
                <h2 className="text-white">Our latest Arrival.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xl-9 col-lg-8">
              <div className="product_slider_one vr-landing-slider">
                <LatestProduct />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide HTML alongside CSS in SO Snippet. Maybe your elements overlaps?

Comment: @Justinas I just added html.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce anything like in the image. Try making it also a runnable snippet. From your image it seems that blurring an element goes beyond it's boundary box. You can workaround that by including the div inside another div that has `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @ITgoldman thank you! I added overflow: hidden to all three css hero-banner-fourteen classes (in the code above) and it works! You can reply it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your image it seems that blurring an element goes beyond it's boundary box. As suggested in the comments, you can workaround that by including the div inside another div that has `overflow:hidden`.